# Haskell: Numerically integrating using recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, numerical-methods

I'm giving Haskell a go at the moment and struggling to rewrite loops in terms of recursions.

I am trying to write a basic integrator which takes some function f(x) and integrates it over the range [a, b] via the Midpoint Method. The integrating function takes three parameters N, a, and b, where N is the number of rectangles being used to approximate the integral.

[Wolfram Alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+f(a+%2B+(i%2B1/2)delta+x)+%2a+delta+x+from+i+%3D+0+to+i+%3D+N-1)

When I try to compile this with GHCI I get a lot of abstract error messages and I don't really know where to start. Lots of 'Out of Scopes' and several 'Multiple Declarations of Main.a [or b]'.

Thanks

```
MPInt 1 a b = DELTA 1 -- Base case
MPInt N a b = (MPInt (N-1) a b) + DELTA
     where 
     dX = (b - a) / N
     DELTA = dX * f (a + dX * (N+0.5))

f :: (Num a) => a -> a
f x = x^2
```

Answer (score 10):

- You've named your function `MPInt`.  Only the names of modules, classes, types, and constructors can begin with capital letters; values (including functions) must begin with lowercase letters (or an underscore, or certain punctuation marks).  The same problem also applies to `N` and `DELTA`.
- You use `DELTA` in the definition of the first case of `MPInt`, yet it's defined as part of the second case.  A `where` clause only applies to the expression immediately before it (in this case, the `MPInt N a b = ...` definition).  (Also, this first use of `DELTA` treats it as a function, yet the second use and its definition have it as a numeric value).